# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove the following
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$$
I need some hint how to start.
thanks!

Comment: You can use induction and binomial identities: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients

Comment: I can think about it as integral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following your hint to introduce integrals we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+1} \binom{n}{k} 
= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \int_0^1 x^k dx$$
which is
$$\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k dx =
\int_0^1 (x+1)^n dx =
\left. \frac{(x+1)^{n+1}}{n+1} \right|_0^1 =
\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Multiply both sides by $n+1$, and note that $$\frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}k=\binom{n+1}{k+1}\;.$$

Comment: $2^{n+1}-1 = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$?

Comment: @Ofir: No, certainly not. The lefthand side is sum, not a single term.