# Compute $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k+1}}$

Tags: combinatorics

Compute the sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k+1}}$$
I tried to solve it:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{(k+1)(k+2)\binom{n+2}{k+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)(k+2)}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{(k+1)\binom{n+2}{k+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)\binom{n+2}{k+2}$$
But from this point I'm stuck.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478862/prove-that-sum-k-0n-frac-binomnkk1-frac2n1-1n1) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%7D%7Bk%2B1%7D%7D%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2102859/42969

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to determine $f(1)$ for
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$$
Notice that by taking the derivative, the $k+1$ denominators will go away:

$$f'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k {x^k} = (1+x)^n$$

Then use $$f(1)-f(0) = \int_0^1 f'(x)dx = \left[\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]^{x=1}_{x=0}$$
because $f(0)$ and the integral are easy to compute.

---

As an aside, and as you asked in a comment, this approach generalizes nicely to sums of the form
$$s_{n,m} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k+m} \binom n k $$
for integers $m\geqslant 1$: The bottom line is then

$$f(1)-\underbrace{f(0)}_{=0} = \left[\frac{(1+x)^{n+m}}{n+m}\right]^{x=1}_{x=0} = \frac{2^{n+m}-1}{n+m}$$

Answer (score 2):

You should start by showing that:

$$ \frac{n\choose k}{k+1} = \frac{1}{n+1} {n+1\choose k+1} $$

Then notice you're summing over $k$, so you're free to take this $\frac{1}{n+1}$ out of the sum as a constant factor:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n\choose k}{k+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n  {n+1\choose k+1} $$

Finally,

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n  {n+1\choose k+1} = \left[\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}  {n+1\choose k+1}\right] - {n+1\choose n+1}$$

and you should be able to evaluate these two terms, by standard results about binomial coefficients.

> 1. The first term is the sum over row $(n+1)$ of Pascal's triangle, which gives $2^{n+1}$.

> 2. The second term is just $1$.

> So the final answer is: $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n\choose k}{k+1} = \frac{2^{n+1} - 1}{n+1} $$

Comment: It is easy with k+1 to the denominator, but if we have k+2? $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k+2}}$$

Comment: @MarkBen Yes, I have to admit I can't see this approach lending itself nicely to generalization. But the other answer is great!

Comment: Thank you for your time! It was helpful!